# Catalyst Control Center (Administrative) prompts for password, then won't open?

Tags: ati, authentication, catalyst

I have a fresh (non-wubi) **Ubuntu 13.04 *x64*** install, with successfully installed AMD Radeon HD 7870 drivers that were obtained by **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > AMD Graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)**. I rebooted after installing these drivers and my system was running 100 times better. I also noticed that I had the **Catalyst Control Center** all of the sudden, so I went to configure my (2) displays there. But when I try to open CCC as admin, a terminal-like window appears, and asks for my password. I enter the correct password, then I see a quick flash that says: '***su: Authentication Failed***' (i think...). I searched online for a resolution and found an old thread from Ubuntu 11.xx and then opened a terminal, typed **sudo amdcccle**. This opened the program just fine. I got my monitors configured nicely... The problem still persists however!

SO! What I am trying to figure out is: **How do I correct the failed password authentication that occurs when I attempt to launch the program via Unity bar?**

Answer (score 4):

*I thought I'd make another answer (can't comment ffs) seeing as though I got this issue on a clean 14.04 install and it took me another step to get it to work*

First thing I did was run

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

As Remy5460 said, but I was just getting a graphical prompt that told me my password was wrong instead! To fix this, all I had to do was run

```
gksu-properties
```

and set `Authentication mode` to `sudo` rather than `su`

It's a shame a bug like this would persist onto an LTS release. This is one of the kind of reasons Ubuntu isn't more mainstream :/

Comment: This is definitely one of the reasons I decide to uninstall the OS. I don't know why this bothered me so much, but it did. I suppose I found Ubuntu hard to work with. IF you are like me, you are having to spend more time customizing the OS and "fixing" it than you are actually using it. I am going to be making another attempt at this OS (14.04 LTS) and try what you have shown me. Thank you very much for the input! I never got an answer when I was watching this thread. Thankfully you guys came around and are helping me out! Thank you

Comment: @derekmx271 I decided to not use catalyst at all after a while. I use a ppa for updated open-source drivers now instead, best decision I've made on Ubuntu in a while; much smoother desktop effects and more consistent frame-rate in games.

Comment: [This is the ppa if you're interested](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/) I just ran these commands to install it: `sudo apt-add repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I know this was an old question but since it is the first thing that shows up when I run a search, I figured I would post what fixed it for me. Found the fix here.

http://ubuntulife.co.za/forums/showthread.php?tid=71

If the link doesn't work this was the command needed.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Comment: I recently uninstalled Ubuntu and quit looking for responses on this thread. I will reinstall now and try your answer. I am grateful for the advice! Will post outcome on my end!